# Dubai Transit 96-hour Visa for a Return Flight

Tags: visas, transit, uae

I was supposed to be flying Emirates from Mumbai -> Dubai -> Seattle for which I applied for an online visa through Emirates Airlines, who applied for a 96-hour transit visa, which got approved. I have not yet used this visa. However, I later changed my flight to Mumbai -> Dubai -> Mumbai (still flying Emirates). My stay in Dubai will also still be less than 96 hours.

Can I use my approved visa for this new flight considering that I'm still going to be in Dubai for less than 96 hours and still flying Emirates? I tried contacting Emirates, DVPC (Dubai Visa Processing Centre - VFS Global), and AMER Services but none were able to give me a clear answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use my approved visa for this new flight considering that I'm
>   still going to be in Dubai for less than 96 hours and still flying
>   Emirates?

NO,

you obtained a transit visa means you are transiting in UAE and your final destination is Seattle, if you simply want to use this visa from India-UAE-India means it will no longer be a transit visa.

From official [Embassy OF United Arab Emirates](http://uae-embassy.ae/embassies/au/content/775) :

**Transit Visa**

"The Transit Visa could be granted to a passenger **transiting to a third destination through one of the UAE airports** by the concerned authorities of the airport. This type of visa will allow the passenger to stay in the United Arab Emirates for 96 hours or less."

Further another online resource [Emirates 247.com](http://www.emirates247.com/news/emirates/96-hour-transit-visa-for-all-airline-passengers-at-uae-airports-2015-09-20-1.604073) confirms the same for UAE transit visa policy that itinerary to and from the same country will not be applicable:

According to an email from Amer Contact Center, a passenger can apply for a transit 96 hours visa at the airport upon paying its fees. However, they have to meet certain conditions such as the duration between the two trips should not be less than 8 hours and **the two trips should be to different destinations (one should transit from Dubai to another destination and not back to the same place where he/she came from.**

Lastly I have confirmed from a reputable travel agent from my home country and he says the same, therefore I am afraid you cannot use this transit visa simply for Mumbai-Dubai-Mumbai.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help. I'm wondering if I would need to cancel my transit visa and then re apply for a visit visa. Or would I have to cancel my flight tickets and book a different flight?

Comment: One more thing I'm confused about is that when applying for UAE visa for my new flight from Mumbai to Dubai to Mumbai on the Emirates "Manage my Booking" feature, Emirates automatically selected 96 hr transit visa for me (although I didn't proceed with the application because my old visa has not been canceled so the new one would have been rejected)

Comment: @Shobit did you login as a registered member on emirates?

Comment: I booked the ticket as a Skywards member, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @Shobit yes system detects from their system that you have been issued a transit visa before, I suggest before applying for a new visa ask UAE  immigration should you need to cancel previous transit visa in order to get new one for new itinerary

Comment: The article from Emirates247 seems old, is the transit visa still granted to all citizens? Any official information about it?